# One-to-One Relationship in Rails returning nil instead of Collection Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm having a problem with a one-to-one association in rails 4. the code is not returning method missing, but i get nil. i have tried adding class_names, foreign keys, primary keys i guess i'm just doing this all wrong. any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

client_submission_data.rb

```
 class ClientSubmissionData < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :client_submissions, class_name: 'ClientSubmission'
end
```

client_submission.rb

```
class ClientSubmission < ActiveRecord::Base 

    belongs_to :clients
    has_one :client_submission_data
    has_attached_file :csv_file
end
```

schema.rb

```
 create_table "client_submission_data", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "client_submissions_id"
    t.text     "json"
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
  end

 create_table "client_submissions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "json"
    t.integer  "clients_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "rows"
    t.string   "csv_file_file_name"
    t.string   "csv_file_content_type"
    t.integer  "csv_file_file_size"
    t.datetime "csv_file_updated_at"
  end
```

**Commands**

```
rails c
cs = ClientSubmission.new
cs.client_submission_data
#=> nil

csd = ClientSubmissionData.new
cs.client_submission_data << csd
NoMethodError: undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass

cs.client_submission_data = csd
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'client_submission_id`
```

Comment: I think `has_one` returns only one object instead of collection that is why you are getting nil not an empty collection array.

Comment: i thought maybe that was it to but when i tried to apply a ClientSubmissionData obj to ClientSubmission i get a NoMethodError. it has to be something with my schema not matching what i'm declaring in the models.

Comment: Got it working, thank you all. You both answered parts of my question, i cant decide who to give the answer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

belongs_to associations use the singular term.

```
belongs_to :client_submission

belongs_to :client
```

Also, I'm not sure you need to specify the class name since you aren't referring to a different model. In your schema you have clients_id and client_id, it should be client_id and client_submission_id instead of client_submissions_id. If you change both your belongs_to statements run some migrations to change those fields  you should be okay.

Generally the model/class_name is singular and the table is plural.

Comment: Ok, i'll change my db schema real quick and see if that fixes. thank you.

Comment: Make sure to generate a migration to update the schema, don't manually update it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `nil` because, there is no `client_submission_data`.

If you want to assign `client_submission_data` do the following:

```
cs = ClientSubmission.new
csd = ClientSubmissionData.new
cs.client_submission_data = csd
cs.save
```

Use `=` instead of `<<`.

Comment: Thanks! that got me farther. But now i get another error. it seems my schema has plural client_submissions_id instead of singular client_submission_id. what is the best way to go about fixing this? should i update my db or include code in the model to fix this?

Comment: Even though it is possible to fix it by adding additional code to the model. I would suggest to fix it by updating your database and following rails conventions. You would thank yourself later.